# Detect forward references (make them different color)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want forward references to be of different color than backward references. This should work both with and without `hyperref` (actually, I use it with `hyperref` only, but for completeness it should work without `hyperref` also).

I need this to check for proofs referring to future theorems (what is generally an indication of an error).

If there are not yet a LaTeX package for this, a new package following my idea should be devised.

---

@HeikoOberdiek Thanks for your example. But I need this to work with `\ref` command not `\myref` (because I use LyX for cross-references). I tried to modify your code but it does not work. Please help to find the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{auxhook}
\newcounter{labelknownref}
\renewcommand*{\thelabelknownref}{\the\value{labelknownref}}
\makeatletter
\AddLineBeginAux{%
  \string\providecommand\string\LabelKnown[2]{}%
}
\newcommand*{\LabelKnown}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname lkr@#2\endcsname{%
    \@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{1}%
  }%
}

% \LetLtxMacro{\OldRef}{\ref}
\let\OldRef=\ref

\renewcommand*{\ref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \stepcounter{labelknownref}%
    \if@filesw
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \string\LabelKnown{#1}{\thelabelknownref}%
      }%
    \fi 
    \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 1%
      \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
      \OldRef{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{blue}{(ok)}}%
    \else
      \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 0%
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=red}%
        \OldRef{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{(forward reference!)}}%
      \else
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=orange}%
        \OldRef{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{orange}{(unknown)}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
A forward reference to section \ref{sec:intro}.

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

In this section \ref{sec:intro} we introduce something\\
and show figures \ref{fig:top} and \ref{fig:bottom}.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{Figure at the top}
  \label{fig:top}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \caption{Figure at the bottom}
  \label{fig:bottom}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: it is not difficult to find out if a label is on a previous page or not, see e.g. varioref. And with the savepos module of zref one can certainly also compare the positions on the current page.

Comment: *a new package following my idea should be devised* -- Yes, sir, we follow your orders ;-)

Comment: Don't forget that floats can often float quite a few pages later than the text surrounding where they were inserted.  This is by design and probably necessary.  The effect would be to highlight a lot of `as shown in figure~\ref{my_fig}`s where `my_fig` appears on the next page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example defines macro `\myref`, which writes into the `.aux` file the command `\LabelKnown` with two arguments, the referenced label name and a unique identification number for this instance of `\myref` (the same label can be referenced more than once). When the `.aux` file is read in the next LaTeX run at `\begin{document}`, then `\LabelKnown` if the label command is already read and the label reference is known. This means, the write command for the label was issued before the write request for `\LabelKnown` and the label is quite likely defined before the reference. Then `\myref` sets the appropriate color for the reference and adds an annotation text for illustration purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{auxhook}
\newcounter{labelknownref}
\renewcommand*{\thelabelknownref}{\the\value{labelknownref}}
\makeatletter
\AddLineBeginAux{%
  \string\providecommand\string\LabelKnown[2]{}%
}
\newcommand*{\LabelKnown}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname lkr@#2\endcsname{%
    \@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \stepcounter{labelknownref}%
    \if@filesw
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
        \string\LabelKnown{#1}{\thelabelknownref}%
      }%
    \fi 
    \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 1%
      \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
      \ref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{blue}{(ok)}}%
    \else
      \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 0%
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=red}%
        \ref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{(forward reference!)}}%
      \else
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=orange}%
        \ref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{orange}{(unknown)}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
A forward reference to section \myref{sec:intro}.

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

In this section \myref{sec:intro} we introduce something\\
and show figures \myref{fig:top} and \myref{fig:bottom}.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{Figure at the top}
  \label{fig:top}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \caption{Figure at the bottom}
  \label{fig:bottom}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### With redefinition of `\ref`

`\ref` is defined and redefined several times by different packages.
The following example loads `nameref` earlier, otherwise it would be loaded in `\AtBeginDocument`. The old meaning is saved via `\LetLtxMacro` of package `letltxmacro`, because `\ref` is often defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Also the actual redefinition is moved to `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{auxhook}
\newcounter{labelknownref}
\renewcommand*{\thelabelknownref}{\the\value{labelknownref}}
\makeatletter
\AddLineBeginAux{%
  \string\providecommand\string\LabelKnown[2]{}%
}
\newcommand*{\LabelKnown}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname lkr@#2\endcsname{%
    \@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{1}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{nameref}% load it now, because it redefines \ref
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\myorgref\ref
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\ref}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \stepcounter{labelknownref}%
      \if@filesw
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
          \string\LabelKnown{#1}{\thelabelknownref}%
        }%
      \fi 
      \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 1%
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}%
        \myorgref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{blue}{(ok)}}%
      \else
        \if\csname lkr@\thelabelknownref\endcsname 0%
          \hypersetup{linkcolor=red}%
          \myorgref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{(forward reference!)}}%
        \else
          \hypersetup{linkcolor=orange}%
          \myorgref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{orange}{(unknown)}}%
        \fi
      \fi  
    \endgroup
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
A forward reference to section \ref{sec:intro}.

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

In this section \ref{sec:intro} we introduce something\\
and show figures \ref{fig:top} and \ref{fig:bottom}.

\begin{figure}[t]
  \caption{Figure at the top}
  \label{fig:top}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \caption{Figure at the bottom}
  \label{fig:bottom}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely an answer to my question. However, it would be better to create a .sty file (and even upload it to CTAN). When I though at it, I realized that I don't know how to define custom formatters (like `\myorgref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{(forward reference!)}}`) because `\myorgref` isn't defined as a global macro. I think your help may be valuable for LaTeX community.

Comment: @porton Just put the code into a `myref.sty` file, add `\ProvidesPackage{myref}[2015/06/11 v1.0 ...]` at the beginning and remove the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, because `\makeatletter` is the default in `.sty` files.

Comment: @porton I don't understand your problem with a formatter, `\myorgref` is just the original `\ref`.

Comment: I want to allow the user to define a macro like `\renewcommand{\forwardref}{\myorgref{#1}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{(forward reference!)}}}` but I can't because `\myorgref` is not defined at this scope. I may misunderstand something. Once I was a LaTeX-expert but has forgotten most of my knowledge

Comment: @porton Your `\renewcommand{\forwardref}{...}` misses the argument number: `\renewcommand*{\forwardref}[1]{...}`.